# Filter dataframe while filter values are not all defined yet

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I am trying to make a simple filter system with panda. I have this DB that contains poker hands along with player moves (call, raise, fall, etc.).

What I would like to do is set-up a generic filter and then progressively filter my Dataframe everytime a player has made an action. For instance:

1/ Generic filter is made of action 1, 2, 3, 4
2/ For action 1, player decides to "raise"
3/ Actions 2, 3, 4 haven't been played yet
4/ I want to filter my dataframe only on action 1 while keep all the other possible actions 2,3,4

The problem is the following one. When defining action 2 3 or 4 with value "", the filter does not work at all. What value do you think I should use instead?

Cheers guys

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('xxxxx', sep=";")

df.dropna(inplace = True)

###PREFLOP###

a1_preflop = "c"
a2_preflop = ""
a3_preflop = ""
a4_preflop = ""

x= df[(df.actions_1_preflop == a1_preflop) & (df.actions_2_preflop == a2_preflop) & (df.actions_3_preflop == a3_preflop)& (df.actions_4_preflop == a4_preflop)]

print(x)
```

Below is an example of a small dataframe unfiltered, then filtered on action 1 == "c" while action 2 / 3 / 4 haven't been filtered yet (but the filters remains active in the formula in my notebook for actions 2 / 3 / 4, they just shouldn't have any value associated yet because I want to filter on action 2 / 3 / 4 later)

```
myposition  tiers   besthand_flop   checker_flop    handtype_flop   topsuite_flop   topcolor_flop   besthand_turn   checker_turn    handtype_turn   topsuite_turn   topcolor_turn   besthand_river  checker_river   handtype_river  topsuite_river  topcolor_river  bet_1_preflop   bet_2_preflop   bet_3_preflop   bet_1_flop  bet_2_flop  bet_3_flop  bet_1_turn  bet_2_turn  bet_3_turn  bet_1_river bet_2_river bet_3_river action1_preflop action2_preflop action3_preflop action4_preflop action1_flop    action2_flop    action3_flop    action4_flop    action1_turn    action2_turn    action3_turn    action4_turn    action1_river   action2_river   action3_river   action4_river
bb  4   Brelan  1   high    3   3   Brelan  1   high    3   3   Brelan  1   high    3   3   1.3         4.6         193.1                       r   c           c   e   c       a   c           c   c       
sb  9   Double paire    0.5 very high   2   2   Double paire    0.5 very high   2   3   Double paire    0.5 very high   3   3   6                       14                      c   e   c       c   c           c   z   f                   
bb  9   Double paire    0.5 very high   2   3   Double paire    0.5 very high   3   3   Double paire    0.5 very high   4   3                           2           9   188     c   c           c   c           r   c           c   e   a   f
sb  4   Paire   1   high    4   2   Paire   1   high    4   2   Suite   0.8 very high   5   2   2                       1.5         5.85    189.65      c   r   c       c   c           r   c           e   a   f   
sb  9   Paire   1   high    2   2   Double paire    0.5 high    2   2   Double paire    0.5 high    3   3                           2                       c   c           c   c           r   c           c   c       
sb  9   Paire   1   high    3   2   Double paire    0.5 high    3   2   Brelan  0.666666667 high    3   3   3                       2           1.2         c   r   c       c   c           r   c           r   c       
bb  9   Paire   1   high    2   3   Double paire    0.5 high    2   3   Brelan  1   high    2   3               1.3                                 c   c           c   r   c       c   c           c   c       
bb  9   Paire   1   high    3   2   Paire   1   high    3   2   Double paire    0.5 very high   3   2   1.3                     197.7                       r   c           c   c           a   f                       
sb  5   Paire   1   high    3   2   Paire   1   high    3   2   Double paire    1   high    3   2                           1.3         197.7           c   c           c   c           r   c           c   a   f   
bb  7   Brelan  0.666666667 high    3   2   Brelan  0.666666667 high    3   3   Brelan  0.666666667 high    3   3   1.3                     4.6                     r   c           c   c           e   f
```

Comment: Can you give us a working example? Like a small mock-up dataframe?

Comment: Sure @Jannik, i have added a small example in the initial post

Comment: Hi, could you show what `df.head(10)` looks like?

Comment: @Laurent I just added it to the initial post